# Where to direct request for advice on CMS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am looking for advice from the experienced community about the right direction for a CMS (content management system) based project I have upcoming, but I'm unsure of the right site to post this on. It's definitely not Stack Overflow, as requests for advice get eaten alive there. Thoughts?

Comment: There generally isn't a good place to ask for direction; it's too formless to be very answerable, and everyone will have different priorities as to what criteria is more important.

Comment: @fbueckert that seems like a shortcoming of this community. There should absolutely be a place to ask for direction.

Comment: It's not a shortcoming, it's a *specialization*.

Comment: Well, discussions aren't really meant for Q&A; how can you even focus a question enough for it to be answerable?  How do you then make it useful for others that read it?

Comment: Read any question on The Workplace. Opinion -based questions are prevalent on stack already, even if we say they aren't.

Comment: Even now, you're all so caught up in what stack is "supposed to be" that you neglected to just direct me here --> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Software Recommendations. Don't tell me there's no place for opinions on stack....

Comment: Read their help before posting; they're pretty strict on what they accept.  It's not meant to be used for direction, but for finding software that meets specific criteria.  I'd not recommend asking there.

Comment: @fbueckert again with the technicality. you just "recommended" that I don't post there. That's some direction you just offered to me. Direction, aka advice, is what this site is built on. An answer to a question is direction. I'm looking for software that meets specific criteria, here is the criteria, can anyone provide me SOME DIRECTION??? Gawd...

Comment: [Here is a great example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167792/how-on-earth-or-whatever-planet-it-is-do-i-win-or-even-survive-on-level-3/167794#167794) of a question on stack that is entirely direction-based, where an answer of YOURS is accepted as correct. The question is literally "what can i do"

Comment: Well...ask if you want.  I don't recommend it because they're not there to provide advice, which is how you worded your question here.  If you have specific criteria, and it meets their scope, then, sure, it might work.  It's rough to recommend that site, because many people won't follow their guidelines, and it turns into a really negative experience all around.  But if you want to, go ahead.  I'm just saying that it's not at all a guarantee.

Comment: Even if we forget the opinion based discussion, what for advice are you looking for? How to to manage building a CMS tool? Or manage the implementation? Build integrations? Or manage the communication /design done with the new CMS? Selecting an CMS? Adaption of an existing CMS? Creating content for the CMS? Based on those you could get sites offered from pm.se, se.se, ee.se, craft.se, sitecore.se to gd.se or even writers.se

Comment: There is this advice in the site-recommendation tag wiki: *Give an example question you want to ask. If you're going to be vague, it's not going to be the best advice and you may find yourself in rough seas.*

Comment: I just learned this tag was added later. The advice still holds.